# SQL Server copying data to another table using STUFF and GROUP BY

Tags: sql-server, group-by

I'm trying to insert records from one table to another (SQL Server), grouped by an identical field and concatenating the contents of a differing field in the source into a single field in the target table.

The STUFF function is tested in SSMS but I can't seem to integrate it into my INSERT/SELECT statement, I think the problem could be down to my usage of GROUP BY and MAX?

```
INSERT INTO [ProductsImported] 
     (image_url, product_id, item_size) 

SELECT 
     image_url, 
     MAX(product_id), 
     STUFF((SELECT ',' + item_size AS [text()] 
          FROM (SELECT DISTINCT image_url FROM [ProductsTemp]) x 
          FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'')

FROM [ProductsTemp] 
WHERE retailer_name = 'Retailer Name' 
GROUP BY image_url
```

I've trimmed the statement down a bit to remove other fields and make it easier to read, they're all selected like MAX(product_id).

The error I'm getting is:

> [SQL Server]Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

Am I being too ambitious and trying to do something impossible in a single query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

give alias name for max( product_id)

```
 INSERT INTO [ProductsImported] 
         (image_url, product_id, item_size) 

    SELECT 
         image_url, 
         MAX(product_id) As product_id, 
         STUFF((SELECT ',' + item_size AS [text()] 
              FROM (SELECT DISTINCT image_url FROM [ProductsTemp]) x 
              FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'') As item_size

    FROM [ProductsTemp] 
    WHERE retailer_name = 'Retailer Name' 
    GROUP BY image_url,product_id,item_size
```

Comment: Thanks! That got me a bit further, I'm getting long results from the stuff function now but I should hopefully be able to figure it out from here.